# Perl: Check if hashref key points to a value or another hashref

Tags: perl, hash

Given the below two hashref examples the following will product different output depending on whether the OrganizationName key contains a value or a `Hash`

**Example 1:**

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Address2' => {},
          'OrganizationName' => 'EXISTS',
          'Fax' => {}
        };
```

**Example 2:**

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Address2' => {},
          'OrganizationName' => {},
          'Fax' => {}
        };
```

For the first hash:

```
my $org = $hashref->{'OrganizationName'};
print $org;
```

Returns: **OrganizationName**

For the second hash:

```
my $org = $hashref->{'OrganizationName'};
print $org;
```

Returns: **HASH(0x1ae17e0)**

This is because the "empty" OrganizationName key contains a hash when the "non-empty" key contains a value.

So how do I test if OrganizationName key contains a hash, and if not proceed? I would like to do this without looping through the keys in the `Hash` as there are alot and it seems rather unnecessary for only one key.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not contain a hash, it contains a reference to a hash. You can easily check if a value is a reference with `ref`:

```
if ( ref $hashref->{OrganizationName} ) {
   print "OrganizationName contains a reference\n";
}

if ( ref $hashref->{OrganizationName} eq 'HASH' ) {
   print "OrganizationName contains a reference to a hash\n";
}
```

Comment: very nice answer. Learned something new and explanation was very clear. Thank you very much!

Comment: `if (ref $hashref->{OrganizationName} eq 'HASH')` is enough for hashref test.

Comment: @mpapec That will throw a warning about comparing a string to `undef` if it's not a ref. Assuming you have `use warnings` enabled.

Comment: @mpapec You are right. There has to be a reason I picked up that habit, but I can't justify it if I can't remember.